# Plugin Development - using template params in a function

Tags: add-on-development, plugin

I'm querying an external timetable database, and I need to get the start and end points of the journey to use in a hidden field.

My template code looks like this:

```
{exp:get_piers:departure_pier cruise_id="{cruise_id}"}
```

and

```
{exp:get_piers:arrival_pier cruise_id="{cruise_id}"}
```

{cruise_id} is simply a numeric value that is set in the EE channel, but relates to the external database.

So I've created a plugin that looks like this:

```
class Get_piers {

    public $return_data;
    public $cruise_id;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->EE =& get_instance();
    //get cruise id from template tag
    $this->cruise_id = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('cruise_id');
    //connect to external db
    $this->bookings_db = $this->EE->load->database('timetable', TRUE);
    }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Departure Point
 */
function departure_pier() {
    $piers = $this->bookings_db->select('depPier')
            ->from('tbl_cruises')
            ->where('cruiseID', $this->cruise_id)
            ->get();
    return $piers->row('depPier');
    }

function arrival_pier() {   
    $piers = $this->bookings_db->select('arrPier')
            ->from('tbl_cruises')
            ->where('cruiseID', $this->cruise_id)
            ->get();
    return $piers->row('arrPier');
}
```

The problem is that the value for $this->cruise_id is showing in the query as '0', but if I try to return just the value for $this->cruise_id (outside the sql), I get the correct number passed through from the template.

What am I missing? I'm guessing its something to do with visibility inside/outside the function, but having tried lots of alternatives, it just ain't working for me.

Can anyone offer any pointers?

Comment: Have you tried setting `$this->cruise_id` inside of `departure_pier()` instead of inside the constructor?

Comment: Derek Hogue, please submit this as an answer.

Comment: Hi Derek, yes, I tried this and got the following fatal error. `Cannot re-assign $this`

Comment: Tried a couple more alternatives, but no progress yet. If I output `$sql = "SELECT depPier FROM tbl_cruises WHERE cruiseID = $this->cruise_id"` to screen, I get the query I want, but when I try and execute it, it seem its then that the `$this->cruise_id` variable is being _nulled_ or _zero'd_.

Comment: What do you get if you manually construct your query rather than use EE/CI helpers to build it? ie $query="SELECT `depPier` FROM `tbl_cruises` WHERE cruiseID=".$this->cruise_id;

Comment: What if you set the variable locally? `$cruise_id = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('cruise_id')` - then just use `$cruise_id` in your query.

Comment: @JohnathanWaters It's not an answer, it's a comment/question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Numpty alert...fixed. The original code was in fact working fine, I had a stray tag in my template that had an empty parameter value - hence the null value in the  SQL.

:-/

Comment: Should we close the question?

Comment: Yes - by all means - sorry :-)